# Return a string using iBatis when the called stored procedure returns an XML column

Tags: java, xml, stored-procedures, ibatis

I have a stored procedure that returns an XML value using FOR XML. I want to transform the result into a string to be returned by a Web service. What's the best way to proceed?

This naive mapping attempt appears to cause an exception to be thrown:

```
<procedure id="myMethod" parameterClass="java.util.Map" resultClass="java.lang.String">
    { call MyProc(#myParam1#, #myParam2#) }
</procedure>
```

I also tried `resultClass="java.Util.HashMap"` and that returned a list of three key/value pairs when the procedure returns a single block of XML - clearly not moving in the direction of what I want.

I should add that modifying the stored procedure is not an acceptable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the code I posted above does not result in an exception.

It produces in a list of strings, which appear to be the XML returned by the stored procedure, broken up into a number of standard-sized chunks. That seems strange, but I can work with it.